# Reference library not deployed as a module

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

How do I reference a library deployment that is not in the modules folder from an ear deployment in jboss 7? I have a common library (jar) deployed ok, and an ear deployment fails because it can't not locate the classes deployed in the common jar from earlier

Answer (score 0):

It should go into the `lib/` folder in the EAR and `<library-directory/>` needs to be set in `META-INF/applicaiton.xml`.

Comment: this is not an option because it would mean redeploying every application everytime you change common lib code that should not require an app change. if you have 20+ ears that reference it building them all is a waste of time for a code change in an external library

Comment: Well, you'll need to run all your tests of all the EARs against the new library anyway. And building all the EARs just takes pressing a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed the common JAR you need to add a dependency in the `MANIFEST.MF` of your EAR or create a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. The [class loading documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) has more details.

The module name of the deployment should be something like `deployment.name_of_deployment.jar`.

Comment: I tried using deployment.<deployment-filename> as the module name with every arrangement of tags in jboss-deployment-structure.xml defined at "https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7". However, none of them were able to read the jar file and ear deployment instantly fails every time due to class not found exception

Comment: Where did you put the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`? I assume too that the jar is deployed before you deploy the EAR, corrct?

Comment: the library was deployed first, the file is in <filename>.ear/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: What does the error message say? Just a ClassNotFoudException?